# asp.net mvc html helpers using property name

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to use a list of string model property names to make a form. When using scaffolding code like this is generated:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.modelRecId)
```

I thought that using reflection could get the same results with code like this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.GetType().GetProperty("modelRecId").GetValue(model, null))
```

Sadly c# doesn't like this syntax, yielding this error:
`Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.`

Any ideas on how to use the built-in html helpers given the property names as strings?

**EDIT**:

```
List<string> props = new List<string>();
props.Add("modelRecId");
props.Add("Name");
props.Add("Description");
//... etc

foreach (string prop in props)
{
    @Html.LabelFor(Model.GetType().GetProperty(prop).GetValue(Model, null), prop)
    @Html.EditorFor(Model.GetType().GetProperty(prop).GetValue(Model, null))
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model.GetType().GetProperty(prop).GetValue(Model, null))
}
```

The above code does not work. Is there a way to do something like this?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a way to do it using the built in `HtmlHelper` methods; however, you could certainly write your own `HtmlHelper` extension method to do this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply `@Html.Hidden("SomeProperty")`

Comment: Hey @max, Not sure how this solves the problem. I've edited my question, does that make my goal any clearer?

Comment: @TechplexEngineer Sorry, I thought `Model.modelRecId` had the property name, see my updated answer.